# Hue is not capturing null values

Tags: sql, hue

i am trying to do a count on null values however , it is not able to count null values.

example of table :

```
Country Id  Id_typ  Info
Us      123 NULL    Testing
Us      124 NULL    Testing
Us      125 Bob     testing
```

this is my script to count null values

```
select count(id_typ) from combined_a where id_typ= 'NULL' limit 1
```

i have tried

```
select count(id_typ) from table_a where id_typ is null limit 1
```

however when i have change the condition to search id_typ = bob, it was able to do a count . i am unsure on what did i do wrong , any advice?

Comment: Like all aggregate functions COUNT(column) ignores NULLs, do `count(*)` instead (and LIMIT  is not needed, it's a single row anyway)

Comment: @dnoeth: this should probably be posted as an answer, as this clearly solves OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You need `is null` and `count(*)`:

```
select count(*)
from table_a
where id_typ is null;
```

`limit 1` is redundant.  A SQL query with an aggregation function and no `group by` always returns one row.